# Chrome Extensions Add Element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want add span in li's. I add spans but they become visible after all of them created.But I want them to be visible right after created

```
h.appendChild(node)
console.log(node)
```

when I do that an empty line comes to console but all nodes created that turn this

```
<span class="l_Right f_12px f_Bold c_Gray">…</span>
```

I want they comes right after created

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating\appending these nodes inside an interaction loop (for, while) then I guess what you're observing an "intentional" behavior.
I don't know how to explain it to you well, but DOM writings are quite expensive and therefore when the interpreter understands that there are multiple pending insertions (or deletions) he try to optimizes the thing making a single movement only when he "understands" that things are quite stationary.
If this is your case (for while loop) then as a counter-check you can try to set delays between the creation of one node and the next. (This doesn't necessarily work).
Also if you try to set a breakpoint and run your code step by step you will find that nothing changes anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This is a sample of delayed insertion.

https://nory-soft.web.app/StackOverflow/20221111.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      font-size: xx-large;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="button"><br>
  <input type="text" id="delay" value="1000">msec
  <ui id="ui">
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
    <li>hoge&nbsp;</li>
  </ui>

  <script>
    const elmButton = document.getElementById("button");
    const elmDelay = document.getElementById("delay");
    const elmUi = document.getElementById("ui");

    elmButton.onclick = async () => {
      const delay = elmDelay.value;
      for (const li of elmUi.children) {
        const span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerText = "hogehoge";
        li.appendChild(span);
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));
      }
    }

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Daniel Widdis, Sorry, I will be careful henceforth.
I thought html was fine with just a link because you can right-click to see the source.

Comment: No worries and thanks for the edit! We like to not have to [send users "to another castle"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) to get their answer.